# Always getting false reading

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean

Trying to create code to validate a triangle for some reason, no matter what I input, it returns as false

```
type public class Triangle {
  
   private int side1;
   private int side2;
   private int side3;
   private static int num_triangles=0;
   private static int totalPerimeter=0;
  
    /**
     *
     * @param side1
     * @param side2
     * @param side3
     */
     
      public Triangle(int side1, int side2, int side3)
   {
       num_triangles++;
       
       if (isValid() == true)
       {
       this.side1 = side1;
       this.side2 = side2;
       this.side3 = side3;
       }
       else if (isValid() == false)
      {
      this.side1 = 1;
       this.side2 = 1;
       this.side3 = 1;
      }
       totalPerimeter += calcPerim();
   }
   private boolean isValid()
   {
      
       
           return ((((side1)+(side2)) > (side3) && ((side1)+(side3)) > (side2) && ((side2) + (side3)) > (side1))) ;
       
   }
```

I tried putting the statement before return as an if statement, I separated it into individual statements,
but i would get the same result

Answer (score 0):

That's because your attributes are not set when you call `isValid()`, hence `this.side1`, `this.side2`, `this.side3` are equals to `0` when you call `isValid()`.

Also this is not how Oriented Object Programming is supposed to be used. But let say you just want to experiment the basics of Java, if you want to make it work, your constructor should be more like :

```
public Triangle(int side1, int side2, int side3)
   {
       num_triangles++;
       
       // you first set the attributes of your object so when you call isValid() 
       this.side1 = side1;
       this.side2 = side2;
       this.side3 = side3;

      if (!isValid()) // this is the same as writing "isValid() == false", but clearer
      {
      this.side1 = 1;
       this.side2 = 1;
       this.side3 = 1;
      }
       totalPerimeter += calcPerim();
   }
```